# Universal Link is not opening in app in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift2, ios-universal-links

Created the URL Types in `info.plist` file and its URL scheme is `http`. Created the `NSUserActivity` Type. Created the entitlements, `UIWebView` in 'ViewController' class. In `AppDelegate` method I implemented below code:

```
func application (application: UIApplication,willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool  {
    let sharedUserActivityType = "com.test.testApp"
    if (userActivityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)

internal override func restoreUserActivityState(activity: NSUserActivity) {

    //don't forget to call super!

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        super.restoreUserActivityState(activity)

        let userInfo = activity.userInfo

    } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions

    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity 
        userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> 
        Void) -> Bool {

    if  userActivity == "com.test.testApp.view"
    {
        let mainListing = ViewController()

        restorationHandler([mainListing])
    }

    if let window = self.window 
    {
        window.rootViewController?.restoreUserActivityState(userActivity)
    }

    return true
}

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: 
        [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

- I referred to link
      https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW2
- Created the json file named it apple-app-site-association

  ```
  { 
                  "applinks":
                  {
                                  "apps":[],
                                  "details":
                                  {
                                                  "teamId.com.test.testApp":
                                                  {
                                                                  "paths":["*"]
                                                  }
                                  }
                  }
  }
  ```
- I signed the apple-app-site-association file, but as I'm using iOS9 no need to sign.
- I implement the method application:continueActivity and return YES.
- But my link is not opening in app, instead opening in safari.

Answer (score 1):

Your apple-app-site-association JSON file is in the incorrect format - appID key is missing within the details dictionary, i.e.

```
{ 
  "applinks": 
   { "apps":[], 
     "details": [
       {
         "appID": "teamId.com.test.testApp",  
         "paths":["*"] 
      } 
     ]
    } 
}
```

You can use the [Apple verification tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/) to verify this in future.

Note as well even if you are on iOS9 you still need to serve the apple-app-site-association file via https.